# Sent Messages are visible in phone Inbox

Tags: android, android-activity, smsmanager

In our ** Android application**, we are sending out the messages for our internal purposes like on the new registration.

Those sent messages were not visible to the user.

But today suddenly We saw that those SMS are visible in the android phone's **Inbox** too.
We were using **Samsung Galaxy Note**, some times back the same application was working perfectly on the same phone.

We are unable to undersatnd why it is happening; is there any change made by Google to send the SMSes from 
`android` phone?

Sample code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Sending sms's and then deleting them silently..  **(0_o)** hmmmm.. quite fishy...

Comment: Android itself does not show the sent message to the user's android inbox sent item. So there is no need to delete the sent SMS

Comment: You should investigate the differences in the SMS API that came about as of KitKat. Many things changed, e.g. non-default apps using `SmsManager` have their messages automatically written to the Provider.